# visualforce popups in Salesforce 1

Tags: visualforce, javascript, salesforce1-app, custom-button

I have a page that contains a text field. After clicking on that field the popup will be opened. In this popup window I select contact or user record and press the custom button "save and close". After the button is pressed the text field will be filled with the selected value.

In Salesforce one app the button "save and close" doesn't work.
How can I close popup window and execute java action? I know that it is not possible, but maybe it have some override?

Comment: Just so you know...`Java != Javascript`.

Comment: Would need more details to understand this. How is the popup implemented, and what code is running when the custom "save and close" button is used? Then after that what kind of code are you trying to run after the popup is closed: another JavaScript function? trying to hook into an Apex controller?